# Romantic moments for Luffy (and other Straw Hats)

Tags: one-piece

Do the Strat Hats actually have romantic moments? Oda sure doesn't focus on love but there should be some hints regardin Straw Hats that love someone, even if is shown briefly.

Usually this question would be very broad but One Piece usually lacks romance.
Sanji doesn't count. Don't talk about him cause it would have no end. He's just on the receiver end (for example you might say Nami likes him because of a certain scene...) unless you suggest there's someone more special to him than all the rest, then again shown somewhere in One Piece.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is a canon answer... from the Word of God himself... even if it doesn't help.

D: Doesn't anyone on Luffy's crew fall in love? Will there never be a romance among crew members? (Sanji is an exception in this case) I'm just wondering. from Naoko

O: Of course they're in love... WITH ADVENTURE! (good one)

http://www.japanator.com/eiichiro-oda-answers-fan-questions-in-sbs-7443.phtml

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that Luffy loves is the sea. This anime teaches us to follow our dreams. There is no space for men-women kind of love.

Comment: Actually there are romantic moments too (another example would be Boa Hancock loving Luffy)

Comment: That was a comedy you cant actually called love. Because Boa likes luffy because he isnt interesting on her. Its not love, its a comedy thing

Comment: It is love. In her arc the old woman says she'sfallen i love. She blushes, tries to hold him... Love can have comedy and there are serious moments like her turning on the Navy for him, tending his wounds...